# C++: Eclipse code checker error related to vector push_back

Tags: c++, eclipse, vector, eclipse-cdt, push-back

The code:

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v1 = {12, 34};
    std::vector<int> v2 = {56, 78};

    //Doesn't work.
    v1.push_back(v2[0]);

    //Works.
    int i = v2[0];
    v1.push_back(i);

    return 0;
}
```

For some reason, the first push_back doesn't work, while the second does. Eclipse gives for that line the error:

```
Invalid arguments ' Candidates are: void push_back(const int &) void push_back(int &&) '
```

Could someone explain what is happening there? Thanks!

EDIT:

The code actually compiles fine. For some reason, Eclipse doesn't agree that this is valid code.

Comment: Seems ok to me: http://ideone.com/zBAw8b.  What compiler are you using?

Comment: Does the code fail to compile, or is this just Eclipse getting confused by overloads again?

Comment: Also, what version of C++? I can't compile due to another problem.

Comment: @quinxorin that vector initialization syntax is only valid in C++11.

Comment: That's what I thought.

Comment: Added some more info.

Comment: What compiler are you using? That seems much more important than your IDE.

Comment: I'm using g++ 4.7.3. It works perfectly. The problem seems to lie in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I compile the code with `g++ 4.7.3` with

```
g++ test.cpp --std=c++0x
```

It compiles correctly and if I try to print `v1[2];`, I get the correct result.

```
std::cout << v1[2]; // 56
```

The Eclipse code analyzer tool ([CODAN](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/designs/StaticAnalysis)) may just not be right in this situation.

Rely on the output of a C++ (in this case C++11 compatible) compiler.